# Show how many times input N can be divided by input M

Tags: javascript

So, this is assignment for my school. There is two inputs, `N` and `M`, and `<div id="text">` should show how many times number N can be divided by number M.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
      <title>Document</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id=inputn> <input type="text"> </div>
      <div id=inputm> <input type="text"> </div>
      <div id=button><button>submit</button> </div>
      <div id=text>
         <p></p>
      </div>
   </body>
   <script></script>
</html>
```

If input `N` is `N=6`, and input `M` is `M=2`, then result should be 3(times). `N=49` `M=7` result 2(times).

Comment: What have you tried ? Where are not here to solve your homeworks unless you try something. take a look at  `Math.floor()`

Comment: What is a result if input `N=39` and `M=5` ?

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a snippet with the answer (it's really simple, it is not how a good script should be done), just run it to see how it works if you can't get over your homework:

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", ()=> {
var inputN = document.querySelectorAll("input")[0].value;
var inputM = document.querySelectorAll("input")[1].value;

if (isNaN(inputN) || isNaN(inputM)) {
 document.querySelector("#text").innerHTML= "Your input is not a number!";

} else {
 var result = 0;
  while ((inputN % inputM) == 0 && inputN > 0) {
   result++;
    inputN = inputN - inputM;
  }
  document.querySelector("#text").innerHTML= "You can divide the numbers " + result + " times";
}

})
```

```html
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
      <title>Document</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id=inputn> <input type="text"> </div>
      <div id=inputm> <input type="text"> </div>
      <div id=button><button>submit</button> </div>
      <div id=text>
         <p></p>
      </div>
   </body>
   <script></script>
</html>
```